# a weird sqlce error: data area pass to a system call is too small

Tags: sql, windows-ce, sql-server-ce

I have developed a WinCE application which uses sqlce3.0.  Recently I have gotten very strange error with a simple query like this;

```
select * from customers where name like 'h%';
```

I connected from SQL Query Analyzer tool and run the command it says:

> "data area pass to a system call is too small"

but when i run as follow, it works fine

```
select * from customers where name like 'a%';
```

i am confused with it. is this a bug or what?

thanks.

Comment: I cleaned this up, but proper capitalization and the use of code tags (the little button with '101 010' on it) would help with the readability of your questions.

Comment: How many rows do you get back from each query?  Perhaps the 'a%' query is returning fewer rows than the 'h%' query.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [bug in SQL CE 3.0/3.1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/b9a4ccdf-aed5-456d-8379-4df39da7d1e5). Try upgrading to SQL CE 3.5.